# Dynamic IP address restriction presence in IIS 10

Tags: iis-10

Are there dynamic IP address restriction functions in Internet Information Service 10 or is there a way to install this module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is built-in functionality from IIS 8.0 and above.

Go to **Add Roles & Feature Wizard => Server Roles => Web server (IIS) => Web Server => Security => Check IP and domain Restriction**

Comment: How can i find and configure it, if i can ask, cuz i can't see it in menu as i saw in earlier versions...

Comment: you need to check the checkbox that is present under security to make it available. - check updated answer

Comment: Please refer detail for Windows Server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/